# Precision, recall, F1 score equal with sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I'm trying to compare different distance calculating methods and different voting systems in k-nearest neighbours algorithm. Currently my problem is that no matter what I do `precision_recall_fscore_support` method from scikit-learn yields exactly the same results for precision, recall and fscore. Why is that? I've tried it on different datasets (iris, glass and wine). What am I doing wrong? The code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import Counter
from data_loader import DataLoader
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as pr
import random
import math
import ipdb

def euclidean_distance(x, y):
    return math.sqrt(sum([math.pow((a - b), 2) for a, b in zip(x, y)]))

def manhattan_distance(x, y):
    return sum(abs([(a - b) for a, b in zip(x, y)]))

def get_neighbours(training_set, test_instance, k):
    names = [instance[4] for instance in training_set]
    training_set = [instance[0:4] for instance in training_set]
    distances = [euclidean_distance(test_instance, training_set_instance) for training_set_instance in training_set]
    distances = list(zip(distances, names))
    print(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 0.0, distances)))
    sorted(distances, key=lambda x: x[0])
    return distances[:k]

def plurality_voting(nearest_neighbours):
    classes = [nearest_neighbour[1] for nearest_neighbour in nearest_neighbours]
    count = Counter(classes)
    return count.most_common()[0][0]

def weighted_distance_voting(nearest_neighbours):
    distances = [(1/nearest_neighbour[0], nearest_neighbour[1]) for nearest_neighbour in nearest_neighbours]
    index = distances.index(min(distances))
    return nearest_neighbours[index][1]

def weighted_distance_squared_voting(nearest_neighbours):
    distances = list(map(lambda x: 1 / x[0]*x[0], nearest_neighbours))
    index = distances.index(min(distances))
    return nearest_neighbours[index][1]

def main():
    data = DataLoader.load_arff("datasets/iris.arff")
    dataset = data["data"]
    # random.seed(42)
    random.shuffle(dataset)
    train = dataset[:100]
    test = dataset[100:150]
    classes = [instance[4] for instance in test]
    predictions = []
    for test_instance in test:
        prediction = weighted_distance_voting(get_neighbours(train, test_instance[0:4], 15))
        predictions.append(prediction)
    print(pr(classes, predictions, average="micro"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're using the 'micro' average.

As stated [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5710):

> As is written in the documentation: "Note that for “micro”-averaging
>   in a multiclass setting will produce equal precision, recall and
>   [image: F], while “weighted” averaging may produce an F-score that is
>   not between precision and recall."
>   http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html
>
> But if you drop a majority label, using the labels parameter, then
>   micro-averaging differs from accuracy, and precision differs from
>   recall.